# ASP.net making an AJAX call with Jquery

Tags: asp.net

I know how to do this with classic asp.

How do I do it with ASP.net?

Can I just make a code page like verifyLogin.cs

And call that page from Jquery?

Or would I have to make a page like verifyLogin.aspx with a code behind page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to do it, depending on your requirements.  Here's a very simple way to start though.  Create a page called "AjaxData.aspx" with no code-behind:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    string data = "some data";
    Response.Write(data);
%>
```

Then use your AJAX call as normal:

```
$.get("AjaxData.aspx", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: If I am trying to make an AJAX call for a username/password login form, is there anyway to make this secure?

Comment: Don't think this site will have a security certificate, if im not on HTTPS should I not even attempt to AJAX validate a username/password login form?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between Ajax and regular HTTP post as far as security goes.  And if you're not using SSL it won't be completely secure anyway... right?  I'm not sure, I would suggest asking that as a separate question.